# AMPscript While Loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I need to display data from a DataExtension (with more than 2500 records) on a landing page via the the API. As you know there is a cap of 2500 records per API call. But thanks to the StatusOutput of MoreDataAvailable I can keep looping until I get a response of "OK". AMPScript supports a FOR loop but how can I get the count?

This is what I am currently doing. 
`FOR @i = 1 to @emailCount DO`

I need to simulate something like this:
`while @statusOutput == "MoreDataAvailable"`

Code

```
SET @retrieveRequest = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[DATAEXTENSION]")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","EMAIL_ADDRESS")

/* Execute the Retrieve */
SET @emails = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveRequest, @statusOutput, @requestId)

%%[
IF @statusOutput == "MoreDataAvailable" THEN
  SET @isLoop = 1
ELSE
  SET @isLoop = 0
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-Side JavaScript will give you the flexibility you need.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[DENAME]");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "EmailAddress");

do {

  var results = [0,0];
  var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
  var status = results[0];
  var requestId = results[1];
  Write("<br>status: " + status);
  Write("<br>requestId: " + requestId);

  if (rows != null) {

     Write("<br>rows.length: " + rows.length);

     for (var i in rows) {
       Write("<br>i:" + i + " " + rows[i].Properties[0].Value);
     }

  }
  rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;

} while (status == "MoreDataAvailable")

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I was not aware that I could use SSJ.

Comment: It works well on landing pages and script activities... Not as good in emails.

Comment: Hi Adam, I am trying to use your script but I am getting the following error,  startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex
 . Any ideas what what this error means?

Comment: There are no string functions like that in my example. Perhaps it's somewhere else in your code?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't like do - while loop, I didn't change your code apart of DE name and Attribute name.